# How I can use order by of the custom post title?

Tags: plugin-development, posts, wp-query

I have two custom post types

1. case
2. client

In case post type I have a ACF custom field to choose a client, so each case have a single client.

Now what is working:
I am displaying all cases on a page and able to filter them using a client Id.

Whats I want:
I want to get a list of cases (of all clients) and the order by sorting should be a client title ASC.

---

I am able to apply order by using client Id but I want order by client title.

Please suggest an solution for this.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'case',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key'  => 'client',
        'posts_per_page' => 9
     );
```

Comment: Can you share your ACF custom field code here as well as post type creation code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `order` and  `orderby` param in `WP_Query` argument like below:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'case',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key'  => 'client',
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

It will list out your posts by title. For more information check official [WordPress document](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters)

Comment: There are two issue with above:
1. comma(,) is mising after ``'posts_per_page' => 9```
2. This query returning 0 result

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, I have updated code. May be you have added `orderby` twice in parameter. Also confirm once your post type slug to use in query.

Comment: It is  not working

Comment: Here is the query as per your args `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'client'
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'case' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title ASC LIMIT 0, 9`

Comment: Check if you are writing proper query with `meta_key`. Also make sure you have a posts in that post type. I have added only two filter in that query to sort by title.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'case',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'orderby'   => 'meta_value',
     'order' => ASC,
     'meta_key'  => 'client',
     'posts_per_page' => 9
);
```

More information of [orderby parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters)

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se] and thanks for contributing to our pool of answers. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: Thanks, @MatthewBrownakaLordMatt I'll check it out.